# Corrupt SD card

Tags: data-recovery, micro-sd-card

i have a micro sd card (Kingston) that i want to extract data from but it's unknown filesystem and it's impossible to mount i guess. It's from an Android 6 phone. Kernel version: 3.18.19. It's pretty full, only 2GB left

This is from Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch) Laptop (Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200) kernel version 3.16.0-5-amd64

/var/log/kern.log:

```
sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[sdb] 60751872 512-byte logical blocks: (31.1 GB/28.9 GiB)
Write Protect is off
Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
No Caching mode page found
Assuming drive cache: write through
sdb: sdb1 sdb2
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 29 GiB, 31104958464 byte, 60751872 sektorer
Enheter: sektorer av 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sektorstorlek (logisk/fysisk): 512 byte / 512 byte
I/O-storlek (minsta/optimal): 512 byte / 512 byte
Disketikettstyp: gpt
Diskidentifierare: 0853DBF0-26DE-460E-BB9D-A33E7DFFA59B

/dev/sdb1    2048    34815    32768     16M unknown
/dev/sdb2   34816 60751838 60717023     29G unknown
```

/urs/bin/file output:

```
FILE002.GZ: gzip compressed data, ASCII, has CRC, extra field (it supposed to be images i guess.

FILE002.MPG: Macromedia Flash data, version ???
```

I have tried easeus. It recovered the files but those were useless.
The pictures were formatted to gzip files but nothing in them.
Mplayer did not work at all. Only ffplay. Here is the output:

```
ffplay version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[rawvideo @ 0x7f8544000920] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'FILE003.MPG':vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: 00:18:40.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18431 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 320x240, 18432 kb/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
   1.16 M-V:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq= 5852KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Only a test picture shown.

I also tried to copy raw data to an iso file and mount it but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Before you do anything, you should copy the drive onto a local file that you can reapply to the same or another microSD card. `dd bs=512 if='/dev/sdb' of='~/backup' conv=sync,noerror` And later if you have to put the backup back on the microSD card: `dd bs=512 if='~/backup' of='/dev/sdb' conv=sync,noerror`

Comment: Tried that, i guess it's really impossible to get any useful data from the sdcard. And  i guess it's encrypted. So, no luck. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's not a solution to your problem, I know you already tried reading from the ISO. It's to protect your data from being lost in case if the microSD card dies while you try to recover data.